# How can I scroll an application using adb?

Tags: android, adb

I am looking for a way to scroll up or down with `adb` for different types of apps.

How can I scroll apps like Facebook or CNN using an `adb` command?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Scroll up:

```
adb shell input swipe 300 300 500 1000
```

Scroll down:

```
adb shell input swipe 500 1000 300 300
```

You could adjust coords if you need more precise swipe.

```
sleep 2
```

also put a sleep before going for next command

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `input` shell command.

Usage:

```sh
adb shell input swipe <start_x> <start_y> <end_x> <end_y> duration_ms>
```

So, to scroll down (swipe up):

```
adb shell input swipe 250 800 250 400 300
```

Or to scroll up (swipe down):

```
adb shell input swipe 250 400 250 800 300
```

Make sure the coordinates you use are within the screen dimensions of your device!

You can figure out the right coordinates using a screenshot:

```
adb exec-out screencap -p > screen.png
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the adb input shell `roll` command:

```
adb shell input roll <dx> <dy>
```

Example:

```
adb shell input roll 15 15
```

Comment: Please try to give your answer in a proper way so users can understand easily. Try to add code block from editing menu where you want to add code part in your answer. Thanks and keep trying.